# jquery ajax and own route in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have own route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
         "Index", // Route name
         "Index/{date}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", 
         date = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
```

How can I call my method in Index controller?

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetIndexationWage(string BeginDate, string EndDate)
{
...
}
```

When I try this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetIndexationWage")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(myVar),
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data) {
....
```

It's returning my page (/Index) but not a json data. How to do this without a separate controller (instance - ajaxController)?

Comment: that route doesn't even match that methods signature

Comment: Please be more specific, put a break point inside of the GetIndexationWage method and see if it reaches it. Does it make it there? If not have you used Fiddler or FireBug to inspect the request/response?

Comment: @hunter , he used Url.Action not Url.RouteURL. Url.Action takes the action or action & controller.

Comment: When I am not using Index route, all working very well (json data returning).

Comment: Nevermind, your route is wrong. You don't have a route that specifies an action OTHER than Index. Without the default route that accepts the controller and action your method wont get called

Comment: Splash-X, I have two routes - Index and Default. It's ok. And method return JsonResult. Problem in Index route, it catch my ajax request.

Comment: Use Include both action and controller name in your Url.Action. May I please ask why you named your contoller Index?

Answer (score 1):

Your MVC Controller Method should use `JsonResult`

Also, as you code is now, your Index method signature will only have one parameter (date), and thus calling your other method `GetIndexationWage` would have to get it's "end date" parameter from somewhere else... if that's intended, ok... just make sure you see that.

Also, your jquery call is calling the GetIndexationWage directly, rather than using the route. Was this intended too? If so, make sure you use JsonResult and know you're bypassing the mapped route.